# Valgrind memcheck result analysis of a bison/flex parser

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

I am running memcheck on my program and i'm trying to solve the memory issues.

Memcheck output :

```
==29633== 3,443 (128 direct, 3,315 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 8
==29633==    at 0x4A07D2E: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==29633==    by 0x42027F: PDcbk(cpfrCallbackType_e, Powerdomain*) (NetExtractor.cpp:1243)
==29633==    by 0x413DBA: cpfparse() (cpf.y:120)
==29633==    by 0x42039B: loadCPF(char*) (NetExtractor.cpp:1253)
==29633==    by 0x420E5D: main (NetExtractor.cpp:1399)
==29633== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29633==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 2 blocks
==29633==    indirectly lost: 3,315 bytes in 10 blocks
==29633==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29633==    still reachable: 16,458 bytes in 3 blocks
==29633==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Line 1253 of NetExtractor is :

```
powerdomainMap.insert(Powerdomain_pair(powerdomain->getName(),new Powerdomain(*powerdomain)));
```

Info to understand the code :

```
PowerdomainHashMap powerdomainMap;

typedef hash_map<const string, Powerdomain*, strptrhash, strptrequal> PowerdomainHashMap;
typedef pair<const string, Powerdomain*> Powerdomain_pair;
```

For now my guess is that there isn't really a leak because i still can access the newly created powerdomain from my hashmap and that valgrind isn't able to see that.

Am I right ? If not can someone explain me ?

Thanks and feel free to ask code details as i only pasted what i thought was relevant but i might have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have map of pointers to dynamically allocated objects of class `Powerdomain`.
The hash map itself did not allocate that memory, so it doesn't clean it up for you.
What you have to do is to free that memory yourself once you don't need it, for example:

```
for (PowerdomainHashMap::iterator i = powerdomainMap.begin (),
     e = powerdomainMap.end (); i != e; ++i)
{
    delete i->second;
}
powerdomainMap.clear ();
```

You probably never did that and Valgrind told you about that memory still being reachable upon the program termination.

Now, if you really need that data during the life time of your application, then it is OK because OS will clean that memory when program exits anyway. But of course it is much better to do a clean shutdown, so that when this problems becomes a real problem you don't ignore it by mistreating as OK behaviour.

Aside from that, it seems like you are doing object copies anyway so I think it might be worth it to consider not working with dynamic memory explicitly and let hash_map worry about it. The data type declaration will look like this:

```
typedef hash_map<const string, Powerdomain, strptrhash, strptrequal> PowerdomainHashMap;
typedef pair<const string, Powerdomain> Powerdomain_pair;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, yes i need my objects for the lifetime of the program because I parse my file to create a database of objects and i need every object until the end of the program. Thank you for your clear explanation

Comment: What is the main advantage of directly using the object instead of a dynamic memory allowed object apart from freeing the memory without having to type delete ?

Comment: `std::vector` will allocate memory dynamically anyway. It is a lot safer not to do it yourself unless overhead associated with object copying is bigger than a pain associated with "custom" memory management. This is related to vector. In some other cases locality of objects on stack are much better, speed of allocation is better, thus performance is increased. In your case you are doing worse of two things - copying objects and working with new/delete yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A memory leak according to memcheck is any block of memory which was allocated during the program lifetime which is not freed by program exit. Because you're storing a pointer in the `hash_map`, this pointer is left unfreed when the `hash_map` is destroyed. You should either use a `shared_ptr` in the hash_map or use a collection which accepts a pointer and deletes it when the collection is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

In the FAQ section of the manual that comes with every valgrind, there is:

> My program uses the C++ STL and string classes. Valgrind reports ’still reachable’ memory leaks involving
>   these classes at the exit of the program, but there should be none.
>
> First of all: relax, it’s probably not a bug, but a feature. Many implementations of the C++ standard libraries
>   use their own memory pool allocators. Memory for quite a number of destructed objects is not immediately
>   freed and given back to the OS, but kept in the pool(s) for later re-use. The fact that the pools are not freed
>   at the exit of the program cause Valgrind to report this memory as still reachable. The behaviour not to free
>   pools at the exit could be called a bug of the library though.
>
> Using GCC, you can force the STL to use malloc and to free memory as soon as possible by globally disabling
>   memory caching. Beware! Doing so will probably slow down your program, sometimes drastically.
>
> • With GCC 2.91, 2.95, 3.0 and 3.1, compile all source using the STL with -D__USE_MALLOC. Beware!
>   This was removed from GCC starting with version 3.3.
>
> • With GCC 3.2.2 and later, you should export the environment variable GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW before
>   running your program.
>
> • With GCC 3.4 and later, that variable has changed name to GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW.
>
> There are other ways to disable memory pooling: using the malloc_alloc template with your objects (not
>   portable, but should work for GCC) or even writing your own memory allocators. But all this goes beyond the
>   scope of this FAQ. Start by reading http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq/index.html#4_4_leak if you
>   absolutely want to do that. But beware: allocators belong to the more messy parts of the STL and people went
>   to great lengths to make the STL portable across platforms. Chances are good that your solution will work on
>   your platform, but not on others.

Possibly your problem is related.

Comment: The problem is with the definitely lost and indirectly lost memory. There is still reachable memory because i have commented the last part of my code where the destructors etc are to isolate the leak in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating memory in your insert operation, does that ever get deallocated properly?

I should recommend using STL containers which minimize the amount of code you have to write:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Powerdomain> > PowerdomainMap;
```

This should have all the functionality you need with built-in memory safety.

In C++98, use `<tr1/unordered_map>` and `std::tr1::unordered_map` etc.